# Can't Insert a document with text_general field in Solr

Tags: solr

I'm using Solr-9.0.0 with Docker on Windows, and I'm trying to index a simple document.

The first thing I did is creating a core using docker terminal

Then I've renamed **managed-schema.xml** to **schema.xml** then I've added one single line :

```xml
<field name="data_field" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
```

Then I've updated **solrconfig.xml** by adding this line

```xml
<schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/>
```

And I've removed those lines from **solrconfig.xml**

```xml
<updateProcessor class="solr.UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory" name="uuid"/>
  <updateProcessor class="solr.RemoveBlankFieldUpdateProcessorFactory" name="remove-blank"/>
  <updateProcessor class="solr.FieldNameMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory" name="field-name-mutating">
    <str name="pattern">[^\w-\.]</str>
    <str name="replacement">_</str>
  </updateProcessor>
  <updateProcessor class="solr.ParseBooleanFieldUpdateProcessorFactory" name="parse-boolean"/>
  <updateProcessor class="solr.ParseLongFieldUpdateProcessorFactory" name="parse-long"/>
  <updateProcessor class="solr.ParseDoubleFieldUpdateProcessorFactory" name="parse-double"/>
  <updateProcessor class="solr.ParseDateFieldUpdateProcessorFactory" name="parse-date">
    <arr name="format">
      <str>yyyy-MM-dd['T'[HH:mm[:ss[.SSS]][z</str>
      <str>yyyy-MM-dd['T'[HH:mm[:ss[,SSS]][z</str>
      <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm[:ss[.SSS]][z</str>
      <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm[:ss[,SSS]][z</str>
      <str>[EEE, ]dd MMM yyyy HH:mm[:ss] z</str>
      <str>EEEE, dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss z</str>
      <str>EEE MMM ppd HH:mm:ss [z ]yyyy</str>
    </arr>
  </updateProcessor>
  <updateProcessor class="solr.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory" name="add-schema-fields">
    <lst name="typeMapping">
      <str name="valueClass">java.lang.String</str>
      <str name="fieldType">text_general</str>
      <lst name="copyField">
        <str name="dest">*_str</str>
        <int name="maxChars">256</int>
      </lst>
      <!-- Use as default mapping instead of defaultFieldType -->
      <bool name="default">true</bool>
    </lst>
    <lst name="typeMapping">
      <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Boolean</str>
      <str name="fieldType">booleans</str>
    </lst>
    <lst name="typeMapping">
      <str name="valueClass">java.util.Date</str>
      <str name="fieldType">pdates</str>
    </lst>
    <lst name="typeMapping">
      <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Long</str>
      <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Integer</str>
      <str name="fieldType">plongs</str>
    </lst>
    <lst name="typeMapping">
      <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Number</str>
      <str name="fieldType">pdoubles</str>
    </lst>
  </updateProcessor>

  <!-- The update.autoCreateFields property can be turned to false to disable schemaless mode -->
  <updateRequestProcessorChain name="add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema" default="${update.autoCreateFields:true}"
           processor="uuid,remove-blank,field-name-mutating,parse-boolean,parse-long,parse-double,parse-date,add-schema-fields">
    <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.DistributedUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
  </updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

Then I reloaded the core from the UI

Finally and using documents in the UI, I tried to index a docuement :

```json
{
  "id":"test_id",
  "data_field":"test value to data field"
}
```

then I got the following error : **Exception writing document id test_id to the index; possible analysis error.**

I've tried with other types, string for example and it worked just fine, but I need it to be text_general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into the app logs, I found that it was stopWords

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Exception writing document id adfczvaer to the index; possible analysis error.
        at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:326) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessorFactory$RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:71) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.NestedUpdateProcessorFactory$NestedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(NestedUpdateProcessorFactory.java:78) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:267) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doVersionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:542) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.lambda$versionAdd$0(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:354) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.update.VersionBucket.runWithLock(VersionBucket.java:49) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:351) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:233) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessorFactory$LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:111) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader$SingleThreadedJsonLoader.handleAdds(JsonLoader.java:552) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader$SingleThreadedJsonLoader.processUpdate(JsonLoader.java:183) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader$SingleThreadedJsonLoader.load(JsonLoader.java:158) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader.load(JsonLoader.java:84) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:101) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:84) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:207) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2866) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:887) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:606) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.dispatch(SolrDispatchFilter.java:239) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(SolrDispatchFilter.java:207) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.ServletUtils.traceHttpRequestExecution2(ServletUtils.java:257) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.ServletUtils.rateLimitRequest(ServletUtils.java:227) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:202) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:184) ~[?:?]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:201) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) ~[jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:600) ~[jetty-security-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127) ~[jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235) ~[jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624) ~[jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233) ~[jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1434) ~[jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188) ~[jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594) ~[jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186) ~[jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1349) ~[jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) ~[jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:191) ~[jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.InetAccessHandler.handle(InetAccessHandler.java:177) ~[jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146) ~[jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127) ~[jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:322) ~[jetty-rewrite-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:763) ~[jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127) ~[jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516) ~[jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:400) ~[jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:645) ~[jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:392) ~[jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277) ~[jetty-server-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311) ~[jetty-io-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105) ~[jetty-io-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104) ~[jetty-io-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883) ~[jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034) ~[jetty-util-9.4.44.v20210927.jar:9.4.44.v20210927]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.lucene.analysis.CharArraySet.contains(char[], int, int)" because "this.stopWords" is null
        at org.apache.lucene.analysis.StopFilter.accept(StopFilter.java:97) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.lucene.analysis.FilteringTokenFilter.incrementToken(FilteringTokenFilter.java:52) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.lucene.analysis.LowerCaseFilter.incrementToken(LowerCaseFilter.java:37) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexingChain$PerField.invert(IndexingChain.java:1142) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexingChain.processField(IndexingChain.java:729) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexingChain.processDocument(IndexingChain.java:620) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.updateDocuments(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:239) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocuments(DocumentsWriter.java:432) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocuments(IndexWriter.java:1530) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocuments(IndexWriter.java:1519) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.updateDocOrDocValues(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:1046) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.doNormalUpdate(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:416) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc0(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:369) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:300) ~[?:?]
        ... 61 more
```

I just commented stopwords part on index and query for now. then it works

```xml
    <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer name="standard"/>
        <!-- <filter name="stop" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" /> -->
        <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
        <filter name="synonymGraph" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        <filter name="flattenGraph"/>
        -->
        <filter name="lowercase"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer name="standard"/>
        <!-- <filter name="stop" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter name="synonymGraph" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/> -->
        <filter name="lowercase"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Comment: Earlier versions of Solr, at least up to 7.7.2, didn't care if stopwords.txt was present but empty. The Solr devs have clearly changed it so that it now throws an exception if that file doesn't contain any entries. A pity that a) it doesn't provide a meaningful message up front b) the error only gets thrown when inserting documents c) nowhere (that I could see) mentions this anywhere in the release notes!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some other id. Since id field is unique and you might already have one field which has this 'test_id'

Comment: Thanks you for helping, but it has nothing to do with the id, it's only about data_field of type text_general, when using other types it works fine